# Rank And Retrieve Migration to Discovery

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

How do I migrate my current Watson Rank & Retrieve instance to the Watson Discovery Service. I do not see any plan as such.

Answer (score 4):

there are some differences between the services so they are still used independently, but if you want to go from Retrieve and Rank to Discovery you will first need to move over documents.

- R&R takes in JSON files as an input. Those JSON files can contain one or more documents. Discovery also accepts JSON input but each
  file must contain a single document. So you would first need to
  create separate JSON files from the R&R source docs.
- Then you can create a new collection in Discovery and upload those files through the API or tooling  (http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/#add-doc)
- Finally you can query the documents in the collection with the Discovery query endpoint
  (http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/#query-collection)
  similar to the select endpoint in R&R.